# Display a value returned by document.getElementByID

Tags: javascript, jsp

A newbie struggling with what is probably very simple code (in a jsp).

I have an exisitng if document.getElementbyID("name").value == "test" working so "name" does contain the correct contents.

I just need to display this in a header so something like

### Inventory 'name'

but this just displays 'name' and not the value (test).

Probably something very simple.

Code in more detail (this form input part part already working) -
   document.getElementById("assetname").value = "";

Then, as part of a report heading I want to -

### Inventory ("assetname") Report

Where assetname is the value in the input field.
I cant determine the correct syntax to display the .value

I think I managed to correct it, probably not the best code -

```
String myassetname = request.getParameter("assetname");
<h2>Inventory <%=myassetname%> Report</h2>
```

Thanks
Active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to correct it, probably not the best code -

```
String myassetname = request.getParameter("assetname");
<h2>Inventory <%=myassetname%> Report</h2>
```

Regards
Active

Answer (score 0):

Please get the syntax correct. I think there is a syntax issue here.

If `test` is a `div`, use the following code:

```js
if (document.getElementById("test").innerHTML === "test") {
  alert("Inventory " + document.getElementById("test").innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">test</div>
```

If `test` is an `input`, use this:

```js
if (document.getElementById("test").value === "test") {
  alert("Inventory " + document.getElementById("test").value);
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("customlbl").innerHTML="Test";
<h1>Inventory <span id="customlbl"></span></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get through jquery like this:

```
<div id="test"></div>
$(document).ready(function() {
alert($('#test').attr('id'));
});
```